# R Getting 2 legends using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a more aesthetically pleasing graph. For some reason I am producing 2 legends at the top of my chart. I would like only the one on the right to remain, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is my code and graph.

```
plt <- ggplot(ac_total_melt, aes(Date, Value, fill = Action)) + 

  geom_line(
    aes(color = Action),
    size = .9
  )+
  geom_point(aes(colour = Action))+
  ylab("")+
 scale_color_manual(values=c('Dark Green','Dark red'), labels = c("Number Closed", "Number Opened"))+
  geom_text_repel(
    aes(color = Action, label = Value),
    show.legend = FALSE,
    family = "Lato",
    fontface = "plain",
    size = 4,
    direction = "y"
  )  + 
  theme(legend.position="top")+ 
  guides(color = guide_legend (override.aes = list(linetype = 0, size=5)))

plt
```

Data:
[image: Data]

[image: Graph with 2 legends]

Comment: It seems like one legend is coming from the color, and the other from the fill, which you don't seem to be using anyway. It's hard to do more than guess without  a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862)

Comment: How about removing `fill = Action`?  I don't think it is used any of the geoms (point, text, line).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I needed to add show_guide = F to geom_point

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you re-labeled the `fill` scale, but not the `color` scale, so ggplot isn't able to merge them:

```r
plt <- ggplot(ac_total_melt, aes(Date, Value, fill = Action, color = Action)) + 
  geom_line(size = .9) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab("") +
  scale_color_manual(
    values=c('blue', 'green'), 
    labels = c("Number Closed", "Number Opened"),
    aesthetics = c("color", "fill") # apply this scale to both color and fill
  ) +
  geom_text_repel(
    aes(label = Value),
    show.legend = FALSE,
    family = "Lato",
    fontface = "plain",
    size = 4,
    direction = "y"
  )  + 
  theme(legend.position = "top")+ 
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0, size = 5)))

plt
```